# Ubuntu 21.04 using huge amounts of RAM just after sign-in

Tags: ram, 21.04

For some reason Ubuntu is using a lot of RAM on my PC. I ran the `free -h` command just after logging in and before opening any application. This is what I got:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        19Gi       9.7Gi       124Mi       2.5Gi        11Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

I installed 21.04 a few months back. I cannot say that I checked the memory usage before, and I also don't see any lagging or evident performance issues, but this is pretty weird.

What could be happening?

Comment: Run the system monitor and check which process is consuming so much RAM. While unused RAM is wasted RAM, so much RAM consumption just after logging in is not normal.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi that's the problem, the sum of the memory consumption of the processes is not even a third of the used RAM

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi System Monitor didn't show it, but I had a ElasticSearch service which was consuming over half of my RAM! I'll answer my own question detailing this

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there was an Elasticsearch process (not displayed by System Monitor) which was consuming over half of my RAM.

This command `ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r` showed:
`3051 elastic+ 54.2 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java...` where that `54.2` is the percentage of total RAM used by the process.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421232/elastic-search-high-memory-consumption) helped me decrease the total allocated memory for Elasticsearch